# How can I remove escape characters from my JSON object being displayed in Fiddler

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net, fiddler

I would like to serialize my C# object to a JSON object without the final text string including escape characters.

The below method is being called through a RESTful design and returns the following JSON object when called through fiddler, however I would like to remove the backslashes so it includes only the double quotes and respects the JSON format.

`"{\"model\":\"Faslev\",\"platform\":\"ABC\",\"year\":2010,\"month\":\"June\", 
\"plant\":\"ONDH\",\"country\":\"Brazil\"}"`

```
public string GetModelBySerialNumber(string serialNumber)
{
    var model = new Model();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DBUtility.DbConnection))
    {
        try
        {                    
            SqlCommand myProcedure = new SqlCommand("myProcedure", connection);
            myProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myProcedure.Parameters.Add("@SerialNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = serialNumber;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = myProcedure.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Func<int, string> GetString =  (int i) => dataReader.GetString(i);
                Func<int, Int32> GetInteger = (int i) => dataReader.GetInt32(i);
                model.ModelName = GetString(0);
                model.Platform = GetString(1);
                model.Year = GetInteger(2);
                model.Month = GetString(3);
                model.Plant = GetString(4);
                model.Country = GetString(5);                                                
            }                    
        }
        catch (SqlException exception) {Trace.WriteLine("Error Trace " + exception.Message);}
        finally {connection.Close();}
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
}
```

If I use concatenation, like below, then the object displays correctly without the backslash, but I don't really want to do this as it seems to be an over-complicated way to write an object out.

```
public string Ping()
{
    return "{Message" + ":" + "PONG" + "}";
}
```

`"{Message:PONG}"`

Comment: I can only get this to happen if I call `SerializeObject` *again* on the string result of serializing `model`.

Comment: Are you using Web API?  If so, change your method return type to Model and then simply return the model.  Web API will serialize it for you.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker im not sure if I understand. If I repeat the serialization process I get twice as many backslashes
 
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelFabrication);

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);

Comment: Sure--I mean that I can only the slashes if I serialize model twice. I'm suggesting that your result is getting serialized again somewhere and that's why you're seeing the slashes.

Comment: @BrianRogers Thanks for your comment, it has has worked. You fixed my problem in a different way I was looking at. You should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Web API, then you don't need to call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`.  Change the return type of your method to your `Model` class (instead of `string`) and then simply return the model.  Web API will serialize it for you.

Comment: What did you mean "Change the return type of your method to Model"? I'm havng the same issue. However have no idea what means "Model".

Comment: @Gandarez If you look at the code in his question, he is creating an object called `Model`, then serializing it to a string and returning the string.  I was saying that he should change the return type of the method to his `Model` class (instead of string), and then just return that object without serializing it.  In your own code, the object/class you are working with is probably named something other than `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your response string as you want then deserialize and return.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(corr_str, new JsonSerializerSettings()));
```