# Json.NET adding backslash while returning json serialized string

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-4.0, json.net

I am trying to serialize a list to json string using Json.NET but the return string has backslash within it, which in turn is failing a json parsing.

```
var x = from d in entities.Books.ToList()
        select new
        {
            ID = d.ID,
            BookName = d.BookName
        };
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x.ToList());
```

The above code returns

```
"[{\"ID\":1,\"BookName\":\"MVC Music Store - Tutorial - v3.0\"},{\"ID\":2,\"BookName\":\"Pro.ASP.NET.MVC.3.Framework\"},{\"ID\":3,\"BookName\":\"Application Architecture Guide v2\"},{\"ID\":4,\"BookName\":\"Gang of Four Design Patterns\"},{\"ID\":5,\"BookName\":\"CS4 Pocket Reference\"}]"
```

which fails all JSON parsing. How can I remove these.

Comment: that's odd, those backslashes just look like normal escaping characters to me.
Keep in mind that if you inspect the return value of this function in the debugger, it will leave those escape characters in place, while the actual value of the string does not have them.

Comment: But while consuming the Json from a client side the backslash would cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: But when I'm going to the service endpoint from Google chrome this is what is being returned to me. And also as string if you consider the strings enclosing the JSON.

Comment: `.Books.ToList()` is probably too much. `.Books` 99% is enough.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: Please read about string escaping (note that this does not just work for C#, but also for Javascript etc) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma

Comment: This should be just fine looks like properly escaped json to me, can you show how you are using the json on the client side please?

Comment: I was trying to format the json string in an online formatter `http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/`. That is when I saw that its not a valid json file.

Comment: Are you using Web API?  If so, you don't need to call JsonConvert.SerializeObject().  Web API serializes the object for you.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323983/how-can-i-remove-escape-characters-from-my-json-object-being-displayed-in-fiddle).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. it doesn't

```
class Program
{
    class Book
    {
        public int ID;
        public string BookName;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var books = new List<Book> { new Book { ID = 1, BookName = "A" }, new Book { ID = 2, BookName = "B" } };

        var x = from d in books
        select new
        {
            ID = d.ID,
            BookName = d.BookName
        };

        string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x.ToList());
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

There could be two problems:

A) You are looking at the result from the debugger. To check for this, Put the `JsonConvert` in a temporary variable (like I did) and look at it with the debugger. Click on the arrow right of the hourglass and select `Text Visualizer`.

or

B) The calling method is transforming the object **again** to Json, so escaping everything.

Comment: I used `Text Visualizer` shows it correctly but I guess google chrome is formatting the json and putting in escape characters. But in IE I'm being asked to save the json as a file and after opening it I still see the quotes.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta As I have told, perhaps one of the calling methods up-the-chain is re-json-ing it.

Comment: @xanatos I agree about "re-json-ing" it. I simply returned `x.ToList()` in a WebAPI project, the method `json`ed the result by itself. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 4):

```
string str = "Your string with slashes";

str = JToken.Parse({your string here}).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

The JSON object is serialized twice.

I solved by:

Declaring the operation contract of the method response format to return JSON.
I changed the method to return an object instead of a string.

The serializing of Jason will be done automatically behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same result, but with doubled escape shashes while I was unit testing some json serialization. Looking at my code I realized I am serializing the "expected" json string instead of the actual .net object. So, passing a json string to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expectedJsonString)` will simply escape it once over. This is how I came here, and this is the answer I wrote, when I realized I just did a coding mistake... Did you just realize yours?