# JsonConvert.Serialize keeping extra backslashes?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, .net-4.5

(Using Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6)

Given this code:

```
var folderNames = new List<string> { @"C:\Hello", @"C:\World" };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folderNames);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Here is what the serialized json looks like (notice there are 4 backslashes):

```
"[\"C:\\\\Hello",\"C:\\\\World\"]"
```

I get this Console output (e.g. unescaped json):

```
["C:\\Hello","C:\\World"]
```

I don't want the **extra** escaping backslashes to appear in the Console output. 
What is the recommendation?

(*Code also available on .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yHJvfu*)

Comment: `json.Replace("\\","")`?

Comment: @CSharper, json.Replace(@"\\", @"\") would work.  If you write this as an answer, I can give you credit.

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225921/json-net-adding-backslash-while-returning-json-serialized-string

Comment: @CSharper, thanks but I already read that post yesterday, and I don't see how that helps me.  Take a look at my .NET Fiddle link at the end of my post, and watch what happens.  Your suggestion of replace is the only thing I can think of to revert the escaping behavior. In my mind, the JsonSerializer should already know that backslash is an escape character in C#, so there's no need to do it again.

Comment: There are no "extra" backslashes per the JSON spec.  Backslashes must be escaped in order for the JSON to be valid.  (See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).)  The output you get in your fiddle is exactly what I would expect to see.  Are you saying that you want to create invalid JSON for display purposes?

Comment: @BrianRogers, Yes. Best answer yet: json.Replace(@"\\", @"\").

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is escaping the slash the same way c# would. \ is an escape character in javascript. The JSON is valid

Comment: Yes, I know. So what can I do to have Console.WriteLine output what I expect?