# JSON serializer adding extra character as '\'in response while serializing custom datatype in custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am using custom JsonConverter(CustomInfoConverter ) to do some manipulation in each of my custom dot net type(CustomType) which is getting parse.

Below is the code for custom JsonConverter:

```
public class CustomInfoConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(CustomType);
    }
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var customType = (CustomType)value;
        if (customType == null || null== customType.TimeZone) return;
        //DateTime currentDateTime = customType.Date??DateTime.Now;
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(customType.Date ?? DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

        DateTime userDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(currentDateTime, customType.TimeZone);
        customType.Date = userDateTime;
        writer.WriteValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customType) );


    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

The issue I am facing here is extra character'\' is getting appended here, So my response looks like `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customType)` is serializing customType object and again default serializer is serializing it(correct me if I am wrong). What would be solution for this?

```
   {
  "Data": [
    {
      "Type": "someThing",
      "Created": "{\"Date\":\"2015-11-05T01:09:21.6721171+05:30\",\"User\":{\"Upn\":\"james\",\"FirstName\":\"James\",\"LastName\":\"Johnson\",\"Id\":\"69cb471e-da83-48c3-8f60-d1bb29d41177\",\"Name\":\"Johnson\"},\"TimeZone\":{\"Id\":\"India Standard Time\",\"DisplayName\":\"(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi\",\"StandardName\":\"India Standard Time\",\"DaylightName\":\"India Daylight Time\",\"BaseUtcOffset\":\"05:30:00\",\"AdjustmentRules\":null,\"SupportsDaylightSavingTime\":false},\"Latitude\":null,\"Longitude\":null}",
    }
  ],

}
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225921/json-net-adding-backslash-while-returning-json-serialized-string) I came to know that it may be because of re-json-ing, 
So, what would be the solution for this?

Comment: can you provide json with extra '\', your string looks fine, except of missing " on the end, is it by your mistyping or this is exactly your json(it wouldn't work then at all)?

Comment: Edited the question with complete json response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
writer.WriteValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customType));
```

Instead you should be doing this to avoid the double-serialization:

```
serializer.Serialize(writer, customType);
```

However, since you are trying to serialize the same object that your converter converts, the above will result in an self-referencing loop.  In this case you need to use a new instance of the serializer.  Try this instead:

```
new JsonSerializer().Serialize(writer, customType);
```

Note: if you are using any other converters (or custom settings), the new serializer instance will not know about them unless you specifically copy them from the outer serializer.  If you need to do this, make sure you do *not* copy the `CustomInfoConverter` to the new instance or you will end up with the self-referencing loop problem again.  To copy the converters, replace the above with the following:

```
JsonSerializer innerSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
foreach (var converter in serializer.Converters.Where(c => !(c is CustomInfoConverter)))
{
    innerSerializer.Converters.Add(converter);
}
innerSerializer.Serialize(writer, customType);
```

Comment: in  that case I am facing below runtime exception An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Self referencing loop detected with type 'customType'. Path 'Data[0]'.

Comment: Ah, yes.  The problem is you are serializing the same object that your converter converts.  So this would result in a recursive loop-- the converter calls the serializer, which then calls the converter, which then calls the serializer, etc.  You can get around this by using a new instance of the serializer.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Brain, it is working, but it is leading to one problem.I have another JsonConverter named TimeZoneInfoConverter which is converting timezone into its initials("India Standard Time" into "IST"), after using this code instead of getting "IST"  in response I am getting "India Standard Time". This may be of TimeZoneInfoConverter is not getting triggered as customType has one of its property with type TimeZoneInfo. Any other possible cause ? I have registered CustomInfoConverter  after TimeZoneInfoConverter in JsonContentNegotiator also tried with vice a versa but No Luck :(

Comment: Ah.  You did not mention you were using other converters.  The problem is the new JsonSerializer instance we are creating here does not have any knowledge of the other converters.  So you'll need to copy them from the outer serializer to the new instance.  However, you  need to make sure you don't copy the `CustomInfoConverter` to the new serializer, or you'll be back to the self-referencing loop problem.  I'll update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Sorry @Brian for not mentioning that, 
I am new to this. Could you please mention how to copy other converters to this new one? I dont find any method or constructor for same.

Comment: Excellent; glad to hear it.

Comment: Hi @Brian , this converter is working fine , but for one of the API it is causing below error,

The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."

ExceptionMessage: "Token PropertyName in state Property would result in an invalid JSON object. Path 'Data.Forms[0]'."

Comment: Sounds like a different issue.  I would recommend opening a new question for that.  You can link back to this one if it helps provide context.

Comment: posted new question ,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559080/web-api-failed-to-serialize-the-response-body-for-content-type