# Web API: Failed to serialize the response body for content type

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Api.

I am having existing application with many api's.
Recently I have implemented custom JsonConverter which will convert Date as per timezone.

```
public class CustomInfoConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(CustomType);
    }
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var customType = (CustomType)value;
        if (customType == null || null== customType.TimeZone) return;
        //DateTime currentDateTime = customType.Date??DateTime.Now;
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(customType.Date ?? DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

        DateTime userDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(currentDateTime, customType.TimeZone);
        customType.Date = userDateTime;
        JsonSerializer innerSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        foreach (var converter in serializer.Converters.Where(c => !(c is CustomInfoConverter)))
        {
            innerSerializer.Converters.Add(converter);
        }
        innerSerializer.Serialize(writer, customType);


    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

After implementing this custom JsonConverter all api are working except one api,  which is throwing below exception

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json;
>   charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Token PropertyName in state
>   Property would result in an invalid JSON object. Path
>   'Data.Forms[0]'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriterException","StackTrace":"
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoComplete(JsonToken
>   tokenBeingWritten)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.InternalWritePropertyName(String name)\r\n 
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName(String name,
>   Boolean escape)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty.WritePropertyName(JsonWriter
>   writer)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object
>   value)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()"}}

You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524379/json-serializer-adding-extra-character-as-in-response-while-serializing-custo) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be that, in certain situations, you are returning from `WriteJson()` without writing anything, specifically when `customType.TimeZone == null`:

```
    var customType = (CustomType)value;
    if (customType == null || null== customType.TimeZone) return;
```

Doing so will result in an invalid JSON object, because the property *name* will already have been written by the caller, resulting in:

> ```
> {
>     "customType":
> }
> ```

Trying to do this results in the exception you are seeing.

Instead, you need to prevent the property itself from being serialized.  That's not possible in the converter however, it needs to be done in the containing type.

To avoid serializing a property with a null value, you should set `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` in [serializer settings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm), or on the property itself:

```
public class ContainerClass
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public CustomType CustomType { get; set; }
}
```

To prevent serializing your property when its `TimeZone` property is null, you should use [conditional property serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm) by adding a `ShouldSerializeXXX()` method to the containing type, where `XXX` exactly matches your property name:

```
public class ContainerClass
{
    public CustomType CustomType { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCustomType()
    {
        return CustomType != null && CustomType.TimeZone != null;
    }
}
```