# How to remove opening and closing double quotes and all backslashes in a JSON string - C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, restsharp

For performing a rest API call with C# I have to serialize a dictionary with parameters. These parameters have to be placed inside the body of the request as JSON.

The API call is done with the help of RestSharp. And the send string is checked with fiddler.

```
request.AddBody(_jsonrequeststring);
```

The problem is that the API is very picky, it doesn't accept break points (backslash) and it doesn't accept double quotes on the beginning and on the end of the JSON string.

So here what it's expecting:

```
{
    "ConsumerToken":"aconsumertoken",
    "UserId":"email@web.com",
    "PasswordSha256Base64":"apassword"
}
```

And this is what I'm sending:

```
"{ConsumerToken:\"aconsumertoken\",UserId:\"email@web.com\",PasswordSha256Base64:\"apassword\"}"
```

I'm able to remove the \" but when it sends that string it also returns an error.

```
"{ConsumerToken:aconsumertoken,UserId:email@web.com,PasswordSha256Base64:apassword}"
```

Is it even possible to just remove the \ and opening and closing double quotes? And if so how? I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

The complete call:

### userhandler.cs

```
public static object Login(string uname, string pass, string conTok)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> loginDictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();
    loginDictionary.Add("ConsumerToken", conTok); 
    loginDictionary.Add("UserId", uname);
    loginDictionary.Add("PasswordSha256Base64", pass); 
    string jsonRequestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginDictionary);

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(jsonRequestString); 
    return proxy.Execute();
}
```

### Proxy.cs

```
public class Proxy
{
    const string BaseUrl = "API url";
    const string ActionUrl = "API action url";

    string _jsonrequeststring; 

    public Proxy(string json)
    {
        _jsonrequeststring = json;
    }

    public Object Execute()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl); 
        var request = new RestRequest(ActionUrl); 

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(_jsonrequeststring);

        request.Method = Method.POST;
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        var content = response.Content;

        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"{ConsumerToken:\"aconsumertoken\"`... would result in invalid JSON. You need `"{\"ConsumerToken\":\"aconsumertoken\"`...

Comment: Are you sure that's what you are sending? I mean, do you use VS IDE to inspect the string contents? In the "quickview"-tooltip the string is shown with escape characters. If you then use the Text visualizer (the magnify symbol) you see the actual content.

Comment: O thanks user1515791 I forgot to mention. I'm checking the string with Fiddler. I copy pasted everything from there, well changed the parameters a bit but I haven't copied it from Visual Studio

Comment: How are you building _jsonrequeststring? Are you including the correct HTTP headers for the content type? Can you show the full HTTP request

Comment: [Json.Net doesn't add the backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18226101/542251) so it's not that. Are you sure the *Raw* HTTP has these and it's not just fiddler making it friendly? If not I'd suggest that Restsharp (which I don't know) is the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're adding the body content as a string, which means that it'll be encoded as a string by RestSharp. If possible, try adding the object itself and let RestSharp handle the serialization etc:

```
var obj = new {
                  ConsumerToken = "aconsumertoken",
                  UserId = "email@web.com",
                  PasswordSha256Base64 = "apassword"
              };
request.AddBody(obj);
```

If you must use a pre-serialized JSON string for some reason, you should be able to do it like this:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", _jsonrequeststring, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

*[NB: I haven't actually tested either of these suggestions, but I think they should do the trick]*

Comment: Well I tested it for you and it works, thanks. This fixes my problem