# RestSharp, response content with unwanted quotation marks

Tags: c#, restsharp

Im taking and API token using RestSharp, all seems to work just fine except that it returns the token with quotation marks.

This is my code and the token variable contains exactly this, I do not want to use a method to remove the quotes, I would like the token to come as it is returned to me in postman, without quotes.

Code:

```
    {
        private const string BASE_URL = "censured";
        private const string USERNAME = "test-juliac";
        private const string PASSWORD = "123456";

        public async Task<string> AuthenticateGetToken()
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
            var requestBody = new
            {
                username = USERNAME,
                password = PASSWORD
            };
            
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("Authentication/Authenticate").AddJsonBody(requestBody);
            RestResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);
            String token = response.Content;
            return token;
        }
    }
```

The returned token with quotation marks:

[image: Token]

Comment: see this SO answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37159899/14973743

Comment: Do you know the response encoding? If it's UTF-8 you can try checking what `Encoding.Utf8.GetString(response.RawBytes)` return. RestSharp doesn't do much about the response, it takes the bytes returned and converts it to a string using the response encoding, or default encoding.

Comment: I think I understood your question, looks good to me. Except the first few words of the question itself which currently look like a typo perhaps?: "Im taking and API token"