# JsonConvert.SerializeObject doesn't serialize my object to a JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Entity Framework with Database First approach. I want to fill my pie chart with data coming from database. The chart will be shown in home page so I have created a method named `FillChart` inside the `HomeController`.

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRoomRepository _roomRepository;

    public HomeController(IRoomRepository roomRepository)
    {
        _roomRepository = roomRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FillChart()
    {

        var dbRoomList = _roomRepository.GetAll().Select(x => new { x.DoorNumber, x.Fullness });
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbRoomList.ToList());
        return Json(jsonString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: "FillChart",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            var doorNumber = [];
            var fullness = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                doorNumber.push("Door Number" + data[i].DoorNumber);
                fullness.push(data[i].Fullness);
            }

            var chartData = {

                labels: doorNumber,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Oda Numarası ',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: fullness
                }]
            };

            var ctx = $("#pieChart");
            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx,
                {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: chartData
                });
        },
        error: function (data) {

            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

After the code line below is compiled:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbRoomList.ToList());
```

jsonString value seems like it is not serialized:

```
"[{\"DoorNumber\":1,\"Fullness\":1},{\"DoorNumber\":2,\"Fullness\":0},{\"DoorNumber\":3,\"Fullness\":0},{\"DoorNumber\":4,\"Fullness\":0},{\"DoorNumber\":1,\"Fullness\":0}]"
```

But when I take a look at inside of jsonString with `Text Visualizer` it looks like this:

```
[{"DoorNumber":1,"Fullness":1},{"DoorNumber":2,"Fullness":0},{"DoorNumber":3,"Fullness":0},{"DoorNumber":4,"Fullness":0},{"DoorNumber":1,"Fullness":0}]
```

I am opening the browser in debug mode to inspect the changings of javascript code

[image: debugger]

and I saw that data.lenght is 151 instead of 5. The result of `console.log(JSON.parse(data));` is:

[image: array]

[I have checked the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225921/json-net-adding-backslash-while-returning-json-serialized-string) even so I couldn't find any solution to my problem. What is the problem of my code?

Comment: Its just `return Json(dbRoomList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` - your serializing it to JSON twice

Comment: you are right @StephenMuecke. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're returning `Json()` form the Controller, you don't need to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` to serialize the object before sent. `Controller.Json()` method will create a `JsonResult` object that serializes the specified object to JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).

Also in your jQuery code, since you've already specified `JSON` as `dataType`,  the `data` returning from the server / on `success()` callback is expected to be in JSON format. You don't need to parse it again.

**Server-side**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FillChart()
{
    var dbRoomList = _roomRepository.GetAll()
        .Select(x => new { x.DoorNumber, x.Fullness });

    return Json(dbRoomList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**jQuery code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "FillChart",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // data should already be a JSON object

        var doorNumber = [];
        var fullness = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            doorNumber.push("Door Number" + data[i].DoorNumber);
            fullness.push(data[i].Fullness);
        }
       ...
    }
});
```

**Other suggestion**

I would put the fully qualified url in jQuery ajax url. I also prefer using `Razor HTML helper` to generate the url instead of manually putting relative path there, because sometimes relative urls point to site root instead of application root.

For example, if you publish your app to a folder called `app1` on your server `www.example.com`. You can access the app by going to `www.example.com/app1`. But any relative url like `/home/fillChart` will actually point to `www.example.com/home/fillChart` instead of `www.example.com/app1/home/fillChart`.

So I would suggest you do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("fillChart", "home", new { area = "" })',
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // data should already be a JSON object

        var doorNumber = [];
        var fullness = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            doorNumber.push("Door Number" + data[i].DoorNumber);
            fullness.push(data[i].Fullness);
        }
       ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

151 is the length of the raw json string.

You never set your JSON.Parse result to an a variable, then loop over the array variable.

You need to do this in your success handler

```
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        var jsonArray = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(jsonArray);
        var doorNumber = [];
        var fullness = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
            doorNumber.push("Door Number" + data[i].DoorNumber);
            fullness.push(data[i].Fullness);
        }
```