# Issue In JSON Result when using JsonConvert.SerializeObject C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jsonconvert

I am getting bellow result when serializing the C# Model into JSON object.

**This is my model.**

```
public class ResultSet 
{
public int RowsInserted { get; set; }
public string RequestStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I am creating an object to the model and assigning the values.

```
{
     ResultSet objResultSet = new ResultSet(); 
     objResultSet.RowsInserted = result;
     objResultSet.RequestStatus = "SuccessFul";
}
```

When returning the result I used the JsonConvert.Serialize

```
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objResultSet);
```

I am getting the JSON result like the bellow :

"{\"RowsInserted\":1,\"RequestStatus\":\"SuccessFul\"}"

The actual result I am expecting is:

{"RowsInserted":1,"RequestStatus":"SuccessFul"}

Comment: Where are you checking output? in C# string having "(quotes) are escaped with \

Comment: This is my web-service, I saw the results from REST tool.

Comment: Try answers to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225921/json-net-adding-backslash-while-returning-json-serialized-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the return type of method to the class instead of a string like this.

**New method:**

```
public ResultSet getData()
{
     ResultSet objResultSet = new ResultSet(); 

     objResultSet.RowsInserted = result;
     objResultSet.RequestStatus = "SuccessFul";

     return objResultSet;
}
```

**Old Method**

```
public string getData()
{
     ResultSet objResultSet = new ResultSet(); 

     objResultSet.RowsInserted = result;
     objResultSet.RequestStatus = "SuccessFul";

     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objResultSet);
}
```