# "/" in result when serializing a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, type-conversion

## The Problem

I try to convert a `C# class` to a `JSON object`.

I have tried it using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` function. But I always end up with `\` in the result.

## Serialization

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);
```

## C# Class

```
public class JiraApiObject
{
    public RootObject rootObject { get; set; }

    public class Project {
        public string key { get; set; }
    }

    public class Issuetype {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fields {
        public Project project { get; set; }
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public Issuetype issuetype { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject  {
        public Fields fields { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Actual Result

This is the result returned when I serialize the RootObject of the JiraApiObject. Full of reverse slashes.

```
    "{\
    "fields\":{
      \"project\":
      {
        \"key\":\"FOO\"
      },
      \"summary\":\"Test the REST API\",
      \"issuetype\": {
        \"name\":\"Task\"
      }
    }
}"
```

## Expected Result

```
    {
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "FOO"
       },
       "summary": "Test the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Task"
       }
      }
    }
```

What is the best way to get rid of these `\` in the actual result?

Comment: What you see in debugger or somewhere where is an escaped string with double quotes that VS has to escape in order to display it... Most likely it has nothing to do with what the actual json object is. Try writing it to a file (`File.WriteAllText("myfile.json", data);`) and checking the file...

Comment: Are you certain that method isn't being called twice? Or that you're not just seeing those quotes escaped because of the debugger? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18226101/2957232

Comment: The text in the Expected Result, is that the output seen in the command prompt, file, etc? Or is it just in the debugger?

Comment: @JacobJAShanks Yes, this is when I save the result to a `string` and inspect it while debugging

Comment: @KOODA, try outputting the string to the console, see if the backspaces carry across to the output

Comment: @JacobJAShanks, by outputting the serialized object to the console I got following result: {"fields":{"project":{"key":"FOO"},"summary":"Test the REST API","issuetype":{"name":"Task"}}}, so without the /

Comment: I believe @Broots Waymb and I are correct then. It is a pain that the debugger isn't presenting the information in a desirable format but your program is handling the JSON correctly, I don't thinks there's any issues there :)

Comment: @JacobJAShanks, In the debugger i got `{"fields":{"project":{"key":"FOO"},"summary":"Test the REST API","issuetype":{"name":"Task"}}}` without the \

Comment: Looks good to me @KOODA, I think your program is running as it should be, your debugger just isn't presenting JSON correctly which isn't an issue. Try using a JSON visualizer if your IDE has one or outputting to console for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backspaces could be a by-product of the debuggers presentation of a JSON object as a string. If your debugger has a JSON visualizer (which VS does) that should allow you to validate your JSON object, otherwise try outputting it to a file or to the console to check the formatting.
[image]

Comment: Perfect that was what i have been looking for ages!!

Comment: No problem, glad your cooking on gas again!